# Send notification to device group firebase node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

After my last request on sending notifications, I opted for sending to multiple devices. I would like to implement sending notifications to groups of devices. With the documentation, I could get by but there simple steps which I do not achieve as: created the notification key, and the notification key name. In addition if someone can describe me in detail the rest of the steps, it will help me a lot.i started but i'm not advancing.

> 2 - Create the notification_key, which identifies the device group by mapping a particular group (typically a user) to all of the group's associated registration tokens. You can create notification keys on the app server or on Android client apps.

YES , But by doing what ?

> To create a device group, send a POST request that provides a name for the group, and a list of registration tokens for the devices. FCM returns a new notification_key that represents the device group.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Mr Franck, I saw your comment last time put I was not eligible to respond to comments. This is why I subsequently modified my request. But currently I was able to get out and send the notifications. thank you so much